# How to get all the word in a string except for the first one

Tags: c#, .net, string

I am trying to split the string in a word array, and get all the word except for the first word.
Like something like this:

`string s = "Hello World I am on stack overflow";`

`string result` would give me:
`"World I am on stack overflow"`
This is what I've tried:

```
 string First = "Hello World, This is First Sentence";
 string words = First.Split(' ');
 string AfterWord = words[First.Length-1];`
```

Comment: Try to use `IndexOf` and `Substring` method of `string`

Comment: split by space and remove the first element

Comment: You really should show how you've tried to solve this problem and then as a specific question about what has you stuck.

Comment: @Ben Ok, good suggestion!

Comment: Are we to assume you only want this for English?

Comment: @John sure, for all utf 8 characters

Comment: Huh, [is that a yes or no](https://superuser.com/questions/946612/what-languages-does-the-character-encoding-utf-8-support)? Do you want to only do this for languages that use spaces as a delimiter for words?

Comment: @John Yes, in english.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can split on spaces, skip the first element and join the remaining elements together:

```
string.Join(" ", s.Split(' ').Skip(1));
```

Comment: Just saying as this took me some minutes to figure out: If you want an string array result use ".ToArray()" method after the ".Skip(num)" method ;)

Answer (score 12):

There's an overload of `String.Split()` that does this for you:

```
string sentence = "Hello World, This is First Sentence";
string words = sentence.Split(' ', 2);
string afterWord = words[1];
```

[and it's a lot more efficient that joining them back up again afterwards]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
    String str = "My name is sikander";
    String data[] = str.split('');
    data = data.Where(w => w != data[0]).ToArray();
    String new_str = "";

    for(int i=0; i<data.length(); i++) {
      new_str += data[i];
    }
```

Hope it works for you..!!

Comment: Try "One Two One" as a test case: it gives the wrong result. Also horribly inefficient on memory and lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one too:-

```
string s = "Hello World I am on stack overflow";
            string AfterWord = string.Empty;
            if (s.Length > 0)
            {
                int i = s.IndexOf(" ") + 1;
                AfterWord = s.Substring(i);

            }
```